# Formula logical operators currency madness

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, currency

Either there is something really wrong going on with SF or I'm going crazy.

I have some fields:

- Total__c, Amount_Received__c, Amount_Refunded__c (Currency)
- Amount_Paid__c (Formula Currency) `Amount_Received__c - Amount_Refunded__c`
- Test__c (Formula Checkbox) `Amount_Paid__c < Total__c`
- Payment_Status__c (Formula Text):

  ```
  IF (ISBLANK(Amount_Received__c), 'No Payment',
  IF (Total__c = 0, 'Paid in full', 
  IF (Amount_Received__c > 0.00, 
  IF (Amount_Refunded__c >= Amount_Received__c, 'Refunded in full', 
  IF (Amount_Refunded__c > 0 && Amount_Paid__c < Total__c, 'Partially Refunded', 
  IF (Amount_Paid__c - Total__c >= 0.00, 'Paid in full', 
  IF (Amount_Paid__c < Total__c, 'Partial Payment', '')))), 
  'No Payment') 
  ) 
  )
  ```

And somehow when total and amount paid are both `34.6` or `32.7` the Test__c checkbox is `true` and the payment status is `Partial Payment`

Shouldn't `34.6 < 34.6` return `false`? And the payment status be `Paid in full`?

If you try setting the total and amount to any of the following values the test checkbox and payment status works as expected:

- 3410.95
- 1246.00
- 42.60
- 3720.30
- 2.30
- etc.

Comment: Is it possible there is a rounding issue going on here? Do total, amount received, amount refunded, and amount paid have the same number of decimal places? Which values are you using in Amount Received and Amount Refunded to evaluate to 34.6 or 32.7? It sounds to me like there may be extra decimal places that Salesforce is including in its evaluation of these conditions that are not displayed in the UI.

Comment: Hi @Kyle, yes all the fields have the exact same precision (16, 2) and while in the layout they display $34.60 I get the 34.6 from a query I executed in the developer console to validate the actual values in the database were the same.